# recyclerview searchview filtering only one item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a recyclerview which contains three textviews in each row. I passed three arraylists for these three textviews to the recycler adapter. Then I wanted to have a searchview for one of the three textviews so that when user search it filters according to the first textview(names). I have implemented it but the problem is it is filtering the textview(names) but with it, it is showing the other two textviews of the original unfiltered list. I want those two textviews to be the ones which were associated with the filtered textview(names). This is the code for my adapter

```
public class DirEmerContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirEmerContactAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> implements Filterable{

    private ArrayList<String> dirEmerContactNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> dirEmerContactAddress = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> dirEmerPhoneNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<String> filterNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public DirEmerContactAdapter(ArrayList<String> dirEmerContactNames, ArrayList<String> dirEmerContactAddress
            , ArrayList<String> dirEmerPhoneNumber, Context context) {

        this.dirEmerContactNames = dirEmerContactNames;
        this.dirEmerContactAddress = dirEmerContactAddress;
        this.dirEmerPhoneNumber = dirEmerPhoneNumber;
        mContext = context;

        filterNames = dirEmerContactNames;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.each_contact_row, parent, false);
        DirEmerContactAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new DirEmerContactAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        return recyclerViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //holder.mNameTv.setText(dirEmerContactNames.get(position));
        holder.mAddressTv.setText(dirEmerContactAddress.get(position));
        holder.mPhoneTv.setText(dirEmerPhoneNumber.get(position));


        //Search related feature
        holder.mNameTv.setText(filterNames.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        //return dirEmerContactNames.size();
        return filterNames.size();
    }




    //Extra part related to searchview
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filterNames = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                DirEmerContactAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                ArrayList<String> filteredResults = null;
                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredResults = dirEmerContactNames;
                } else {
                    filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
                }

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;
                return results;
            }
        };
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> getFilteredResults(String constraint) {

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String item : dirEmerContactNames) {
            if (item.toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                results.add(item);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }




    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mNameTv;
        private TextView mAddressTv;
        private TextView mPhoneTv;
        private ImageView mCallBtn;
        private Context viewholderContext;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mNameTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            mAddressTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemAddress);
            mPhoneTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPhoneNumber);
            mCallBtn = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCallIcon);
            viewholderContext = itemView.getContext();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic `Filterable` adapter and override its `matches()` method

Comment: Create a custom class with 3 properties instead of storing it as separate values in 3 array lists

Comment: And create one array list for the custom object

Comment: pskink I dont't even know how to use a generic class. How can I modify my existing code. Any idea?

Comment: Samuel can you please elaborate I can make a data class but then how to use that still not getting